# Integrals of quantile function

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions, quantile-function

Suppose $X = [0,1]$ and we have two cumulative distribution functions $F$ and $G$ on $X$ of two random variables.  I've just read the claim $$\int_0^1 |F^{-1}(x) - G^{-1}(x)|dx = \int_0^1|F(y) - G(y)|dy$$

where the only reason described is "by Fubini's theorem".  This is insanity to me.  I know that under the uniform Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, $F^{-1}(x)$ has law $F$ and similarly for $G$ so the left hand integral is the expected value of the absolute value of the difference between two random variables with cdfs $F$, $G$, but I have no clue how to relate this to the integral on the right hand side.  Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively it should be simple: it amounts to saying that the green areas below are equal in the two charts, as there is simply a reflection in the bottom-left to top-right diagonal to achieve the inverse of the cumulative distribution functions

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks for the plot, this makes sense.  How would I show this rigorously?

Comment: One way might be something like define $g(x,y)=1$ when $F^{-1}(x)\le y \le G^{-1}(x)$ or $G^{-1}(x)\le y \le F^{-1}(x)$ and $0$ otherwise, then show  this is equal to $h(x,y)=1$ when $G(y)\le x \le F(y)$ or $F(y)\le x \le G(y)$ and $0$ otherwise, and then conclude $\int\int g(x,y) \,dy \,dx=\int\int h(x,y) \,dx \,dy$ i.e.  $\int |F^{-1}(x) - G^{-1}(x)|\,dx = \int |F(y) - G(y)|\,dy$